# How do I add multiple Perl modules to Makefile.PL?

Tags: perl, makemaker

Looking for some insight on how to add multiple PM files to the MakeMaker script?

I see [this documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.html#How-To-Write-A-Makefile.PL) and all the examples look like one file is added, how do I add multiple files?

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

WriteMakefile(
   NAME => 'Your::Module',
   VERSION_FROM => 'lib/Your/Module.pm'
);
```

Do I just add another set of values?

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

WriteMakefile(
   NAME => 'Your::Module',
   VERSION_FROM => 'lib/Your/Module.pm'

   NAME => 'Your::Module2',
   VERSION_FROM => 'lib/Your/Module2.pm'
);
```

Comment: Why do you need to add them there? 'NAME' is a name of main modules in distribution, so you don't need to add more modules.

Comment: Actually, NAME is the distribution name. It doesn't have to be a module name at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try to use `PM`.  The [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://perldoc.perl.org/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.html#How-To-Write-A-Makefile.PL) doc says:

> Hashref of .pm files and *.pl files to
>   be installed. e.g.

I went looking through some other modules I downloaded from CPAN for an example of its usage, and I found it in the [GD](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GD/) [Makefile.PL](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LDS/GD-2.44/Makefile.PL) code:

```
WriteMakefile(
    'NAME'  => 'GD',
    'VERSION_FROM'  => 'GD.pm',
    'PREREQ_PM' => {
            'Math::Trig' => 0,
            },
    'PM'        => { 'GD.pm' => '$(INST_LIBDIR)/GD.pm',
                     'GD/Polyline.pm' => '$(INST_LIBDIR)/GD/Polyline.pm',
                     'GD/Polygon.pm' => '$(INST_LIBDIR)/GD/Polygon.pm',
                     'GD/Simple.pm' => '$(INST_LIBDIR)/GD/Simple.pm',
                     'GD/Image.pm' => '$(INST_LIBDIR)/GD/Image.pm',
                     'GD/Group.pm' => '$(INST_LIBDIR)/GD/Group.pm',
                     'qd.pl' => '$(INST_LIBDIR)/qd.pl'},
```

I doubt the code you posted would work because the hash you are passing to the `WriteMakefile` function has duplicate keys.

Comment: thnx that makes sense. One other question is if the new .pm file has a CPAN library dependency do I need to add that here as well?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you cannot figure it out from the documentation. http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils::MakeMaker#PREREQ_PM

Comment: If you structure your lib/ directory with the module name (e.g. lib/GD/Polyline.pm), you don't need to put the files in PM.

Comment: What brian said, PM is only necessary if MakeMaker doesn't pick them up for you.  Stick your modules into `lib` and you're done.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is: do nothing.  Your original code and layout is fine.  MakeMaker will find your modules in `lib` without you lifting a finger.  Try it and see.

Explicitly writing out `PM` as in toolic's answer is unnecessary and brittle.

Answer (score 3):

[toolic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117508/how-to-add-multiple-files-to-perl-makemaker/2117844#2117844) already points you to the docs, but I'll answer the other part of the question (although it is also in the docs):

`NAME` is the string Makemaker uses for the distribution name. Although this is often the main module, it can really be anything you like.

`VERSION_FROM` tells Makemaker that it should take the `$VERSION` from a specific file and use that at the distribution version. Most often, people use the version of the main module as the distribution version, but you don't have to do that.